# Need to reduce dnsmasq timeout

Tags: domain-name-system, debian

I am trying to implement a mechanism whereby, when dns server is not accessible, a fast reply is sent with a default address (or anything, as long as it is fast, as the client - asterisk - requests this synchronously and its sip stack goes bananas).

I've setup dnsmasq, and looking at dig replies, it works, until ttl goes to zero. Then, requests again take an awful lot of time - 10 to 20 secs.

I've tried to add options timeout:2 attempts:1 as a param, no change at all (restarting dnsmasq, etc...), I've tried auth-ttl=1000, no luck either

Average dns response time is less than 100ms not cached, I'd like that anything above 1 sec is returned with an error, and not retried.

Can I do this ? How ?

Thanks for the help - OS is a debian 8.5

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a compile time option for dnsmasq.

See [dnsmasq-discuss](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2009q3/003297.html)http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2009q3/003297.html.

> There are timeouts in dnsmasq too, which are only changeable by
>   re-compiling. Under very heavy load, dnsmasq will only hold onto a query
>   for 10 seconds. It always drops unanswered queries after 4 times that
>   (ie 40 seconds.) This is set in src/config.h